# Is Group Testing feasible (for a virus) when individual testing is not viable (as was done for disease screening of draftees in WW II)?

Tags: binomial-distribution, computational-statistics, resampling, medicine

Background:

Today, Andrew M.  Governor of the State Of New York, stated (and he claims for the very first time the use of the word ‘cannot’ in his news briefing), that he could not possibly test on the level needed (millions of NY residents) to determine if it is safe to open up the economy (but still likely with social distancing practices still in place) in his daily pandemic briefing. But perhaps, it can be, even with limited resources, based on the science of Group Testing. Some background per Wikipedia on the origin of the science at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing, to quote:

> the origins of group testing can be traced back to a single report[2] written by a single person: Robert Dorfman.[3] The motivation arose during the Second World War when the United States Public Health Service and the Selective service embarked upon a large-scale project to weed out all syphilitic men called up for induction. Testing an individual for syphilis involves drawing a blood sample from them and then analysing the sample to determine the presence or absence of syphilis. At the time, performing this test was expensive, and testing every soldier individually would have been very expensive and inefficient.[3]

In the current context, a viral sample (most recent is a saliva-based test) is taken and placed in a tube filled with an appropriate medium to preserve and distribute throughout the solution the virus. Then, successive small samples are extracted from the fluid until a result is achieved in a group testing protocol assigned back to the individual.

More descriptively per the Wikipedia source:

> In statistics and combinatorial mathematics, group testing is any procedure that breaks up the task of identifying certain objects into tests on groups of items, rather than on individual ones. First studied by Robert Dorfman in 1943, group testing is a relatively new field of applied mathematics that can be applied to a wide range of practical applications and is an active area of research today.

And, as to design schemes:

> Schemes for carrying out group testing can be simple or complex and the tests involved at each stage may be different. Schemes in which the tests for the next stage depend on the results of the previous stages are called adaptive procedures, while schemes designed so that all the tests are known beforehand are called non-adaptive procedures. The structure of the scheme of the tests involved in a non-adaptive procedure is known as a pooling design.

And, in the case of a pandemic virus, the best model may be either probability-based or purely combinatorial in nature, to expand:

> In probabilistic models, the defective items are assumed to follow some probability distribution and the aim is to minimise the expected number of tests needed to identify the defectiveness of every item. On the other hand, with combinatorial group testing, the goal is to minimise the number of tests needed in a 'worst-case scenario' – that is, create a minmax algorithm – and no knowledge of the distribution of defectives is assumed.[3]

Also, a  group-testing problem can be referred to as noisy if there is a chance that a group test’s result is erroneous (a false positive when the test contained no defectives/or no microbe). This apparently can be addressed by ‘The Bernoulli noise model’  based upon the assumption that this associated probability is a constant. Also, group testing can be extended by allowing for more than two possible test outcomes.

See this work by [‘An Efficient for Combinatorial Group Testing Algorithm’](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36899-8_29) and relatedly [this 2013 work](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaarti/pubs/GlobalSIP16_ChenYSK.pdf).

[EDIT] Based on comments, is this a medical-related
questions?

My answer, there is a medical aspect, relating certainly to the assignment of the prevalence rate of infection in a pandemic population (which, by the way, for coronavirus is, per the web, around 1%.) The latter percentage, based on the original source paper by Robert Dorfman, indicates a group size of 11. So, if one accepts the statistical validity of the group test methodology, then, statisticians should support this route over single testing, if feasible (meaning, for example, can saliva-based sampling support multiple tests?).

If there is a reason or concern or shortcoming of the group test methodology, please comment otherwise affirm, because, to the best of my knowledge, there are no plans to implement anything other than single person testing, which cannot even be currently implemented.

Did find also probability theory supporting material on Math SE towards understanding the Group Test protocol [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967808/grouping-blood-tests-binomial-distribution). Also found another the Math SE thread [at here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302703/group-testing-of-individuals-for-disease) titled 'Group Testing of Individuals for Disease', which interestingly looks at a problem with assigned group sizes.

[EDIT][EDIT] **IMPORTANT UPDATE** as also noted in the comment section:

On June 20, 2020, a posted news article on the employment of mass group testing!

To quote in part:

> Objectives: Herein, we developed and evaluated multi-stage group testing schemes that test samples in groups of various pool sizes in multiple stages. Through this approach, groups of negative samples can be eliminated with a single test, avoiding the need for individual testing and achieving considerable savings of resources.

Link: https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.10.20061176v2

Note, as to date, only 40 views, so it is not likely that I can accept full credit, but ....

Comment: Just as a side comment: I don't trust Wikipedia as a primary source, or even a terribly reliable secondary source, on much of anything except maybe mathematics and physics and chemistry. It's very biased; that wouldn't be a problem in and of itself (I'm biased), except that they pretend they're not biased, and that they're objective.

Comment: What is your precise question? Whether this is feasible depends on a lot of factors that have little to do with statistics.

Comment: Well, I think sampling theory and things like 'The Bernoulli noise model' as tools to improve a Group Test protocol are definite in the realm of statistics. What I would like is feedback on how probability-based grouping (as the young, non-minority, healthy...) appears to heavily compose the safe non-infected group which could greatly reduce the amount of testing required. Perhaps a reference somewhere?

Comment: Also, assuming probability-based grouping with an estimate '1-p'  that a person in this attribute constructed group (more statistics), exactly how large in counts does one dare to go given the associated cost and material constraints on the max # of test and statistical projections of # of test that may be required (more statistics).

Comment: Did find a prior SE thread answering the question of the expected number of positive tests in a group presented here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967808/grouping-blood-tests-binomial-distribution .

Comment: Also found another answer on the Math SE thread titled 'Group Testing of Individuals for Disease', which interestingly looks at a problem with assigned group sizes. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302703/group-testing-of-individuals-for-disease .

Comment: This is probably more of a biological/medical question ...

Comment: The medical part is the prevalence rate in the pandemic population, which for coronavirus is, per the web, around 1%. This percentage, by the way, based on the original source paper by Robert Dorfman, indicates a group size of 11. So, if one accepts the statistical validity of the group test methodology, then, statisticians should support this route over single testing, if feasible (meaning if saliva sampling can support multiple tests?).

Comment: On June 20, 2020, a posted news article on the employment of mass group testing! To quote: "Objectives: Herein, we developed and evaluated multi-stage group testing schemes that test samples in groups of various pool sizes in multiple stages. Through this approach, groups of negative samples can be eliminated with a single test, avoiding the need for individual testing and achieving considerable savings of resources." Link: https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.10.20061176v2 Note, as to date, only 40 views, so it is not likely that I can accept full credit, but I gladly will!!!!